# Filtering data using rest api fetched from Document library in SharePoint

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am able to fetch the documents that are uploaded into the document library of SharePoint online. Now I want to filter the contents that are getting fetched based on a Lookup column and Choice column. But filter is not working in rest api. Can anyone help here? Below is the part of the url I am using.

```
/items?$select=,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$
                                              filter=FieldValuesAsText eq ‘Workbook.xlsx'",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter data by file name, we can use the rest api below.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DL')/items?$select=*,FieldValuesAsText&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$Filter=FileLeafRef eq 'Workbook.xlsx'
```

If you want to filter data base on lookup field and choice file, we can use this. In my test, the lookup field is "MyLookup" and choice field is "MyChoice".

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DL')/items?$select=*,FieldValuesAsText,MyLookup/Title&$expand=MyLookup&$Filter=MyChoice eq 'Choice1' and MyLookup/Title eq 'lookup1'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
/_api/web/Lists('ListGUID')/items?$select=FieldValuesAsText/FileRef&$expand=FieldValuesAsText&$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'filename.txt'
```